# jython date conversion

Tags: python, jython, date-conversion

Given a string as below, I need to convert:

1 Dec 2008 06:43:00 +0100

to

MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SSAM

using jython what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have jython handy, but I'd expect something like this to work:

```
import java
sdf = java.text.SimpleDateFormat

fmt_in = sdf('d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')
fmt_out = sdf('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ssaa')

fmt_out.format(fmt_in.parse(time_str))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jython](http://www.jython.org/) 2.5b0 (beta) has an implementation of the [time module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-time.html) that includes

> `strptime(string[, format])`.
>
> Parse a string representing a time according to a format. The return value is a struct_time as returned by gmtime() or localtime().

(`strptime` is missing in Jython2.2.1).

A python version of the conversion formats will look like (not sure of the zone component):

```
import time
mytime = time.strptime("1 Dec 2008 06:43:00 +0100", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
new_time_string = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p", mytime)
```

Comment: jython 2.2.1 doesnt support time.strptime.

Comment: As of jython 2.5.2, sadly the built in strptime does not detect most errors and returns a bogus time instead: http://bugs.jython.org/issue1692.

As an alternative, you could try using a pure Python implementation of strptime: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/56036-pure-python-strptime/

Comment: When time.strptime() wont do, you may turn back to the Java side - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/